# how can I add custom UI to dynamics CRM client

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to add custom UI ( frame containing buttons ) to MS Dynamics CRM 2013. 
I am really new to Dynamics CRM and scripting. On MSDN there are several ways as per below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc150829.aspx

I am confused between IFRAME and Form Scripting.

I am not sure what is exact difference between two and how implementation differ. can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IFRAMES:**

You would typically use an iframe when you want to embed a custom UI/form/control. You mention custom buttons, so this is likely what you want to use.

Iframes can be embedded in your form in 2 ways: through adding an iframe component on your form and specifying the URL or adding a web resource to your form, which can point to a custom html page that you can add through CRM customizations. The second method is likely the one that fits what you are trying to do.

You can then add various types of functionality through the page that updates data through calling the SOAP or REST API's that CRM exposes. You will likely want to check out the [CRM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321).

**Form scripts:**

Form scripting can be used to manipulate data, requirement of fields, showing/hiding of controls or sections, etc.

**Ribbon Buttons:**

Another thing to mention is that ribbon buttons are often the best way to add functionality like you are describing to your form. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx).

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: :Thanks a ton. I have created a java script web resource and added that web resource on form load event and I could see the customise UI. I want to make UI which can be common to all pages in CRM. I want to support CTI functionality in dynamics crm for this I want develop UI which is common among all pages. is there any way we can achieve this Dynamics CRM.

Comment: @blue sam did you get your answer.I want to do the same

Comment: Sorry for the late response. There definitely is a way to integrate CTI, but unless your phone provider already has a solution for Dynamics, it could be fairly involved depending on the provider.